# Changed folder structure in Xcode Project not reflected in Git Repository

Tags: xcode, git

I have an Xcode project that is under version control. I've grouped the classes in the project navigator into folders based on what the classes do (eg. Models, Views, Controllers, etc.). However, these folder structures seem local to my machine and it is not reflected in my own local git repository, or if I do a git pull from another machine, the folders that I've created or organized my classes into don't appear. So, How do you get the changes you make (organizing the classes into folders) to reflect in your local and remote repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the adding a folder or directory manually inside the local repository to work for  me. Create the folder in the repository,`git add folder_name/` to actually track and add it to the repo. The files then can be moved into this folder. Depending on how you move it, you may need to do `git rm <file_name>` and `git add </folder_name/file_name>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sh
# modified, new and deleted files
git add -A
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig)

Comment: No, it did not work, but what did work is that I added folders in my local git repository and did a `git add folder_name/` and then moved my class files into the folder. Worked like a charm for me.